# Observable from array poll server

Tags: rxjs, observable

I'm trying to create an Observable from an array of items that each regularly check for server updates and then sends an action when it gets the result it wants for each item.

The answer below is helpful, however not quite what I'm looking for

This is the other approach I've been trying:

```
export function handleProcessingScenes(action$,store) {
  return action$.ofType(REQUEST_ALL_SCENES_BY_LOCATION_FULFILLED)
    .switchMap(({ scenesByLocation }) => Observable.from(scenesByLocation))
    .filter(scene => scene.scenePanoTask)
    .mergeMap(scene => updateScene(scene))
}

function updateScene(scene) {
  return Observable.interval(3000)
    .flatMap(() => requestSceneUpdates(scene.id))
    .takeWhile(res =>  res.payload.status < 4)
    .timeout(600000, Observable.throw(new Error('Timeout')))

}
```

The API function returns an Observable

```
export function requestSceneUpdates(sceneId){

  console.log('requestSceneUpdate')

  const request = fetch(`${API_URL}/scene/task/${sceneId}/update`, {
    method: 'get',
    credentials: 'include',
    crossDomain: true,
  }).then(res => res.json())

  return Observable.fromPromise(request)
}
```

However this only calls the 'requestSceneUpdate' function once.

I basically want to call that function every 3 seconds for each scene in scenesByLocation. I then want to return an action when each one is finished.

The epic that I have for a single scene is

```
export function  sceneProcessingUpdate(action$) {
  return action$.ofType(REQUEST_SCENE_PROCESSING_TASK_SUCCESS)
    .switchMap(({task}) =>
      Observable.timer(0, 30000).takeUntil(action$.ofType( REQUEST_SCENE_PROCESSING_TASK_UPDATE_SUCCESS))
        .exhaustMap(() =>
          requestSceneUpdates(task.id)
            .map((res) => {
              if (res.error) 
                return { type: REQUEST_SCENE_PROCESSING_TASK_UPDATE_FAILED, message: res.message }
              else if(res.payload.status === 4) 
                return { type: REQUEST_SCENE_PROCESSING_TASK_UPDATE_SUCCESS, task:  res.payload }
              else 
                return requestSceneProcessingTaskMessage(res.payload)
            })
            .catch(err => { return { type: REQUEST_SCENE_PROCESSING_TASK_UPDATE_FAILED, message: err } })
        )
    )
}
```

Comment: I think it would be easier to describe what you want to achieve and what are the inputs.

Comment: Thanks I have added some more detail.

Comment: So you want the `requestSceneUpdates` to stop firing each 3 seconds after it succeded? But only for that scene or for all scenes? The way I see it, I would use a retry mechanism, not a timer. So if it fails, try again after 3 seconds (until it doesn't fail anymore)...

Comment: It looks like the problem is that you don't return an Observable in `catch`'s callback. You should wrap it with eg. `Observable.of()`. Otherwise post the entire error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this. The idea is to retry the scene update if it fails, after 3 seconds and not use a timer.

```
export function handleProcessingScenes(action$) {
  return action$.ofType(REQUEST_ALL_SCENES_BY_LOCATION_FULFILLED)
    .switchMap(({ scenesByLocation }) => Observable.from(scenesByLocation))
    .filter(scene => scene.scenePanoTask)
    .mergeMap(scene => updateScene(scene));
}

function updateScene(scene) {
  return requestSceneUpdates(scene.id)
    .map((res) => {
      if (res.error)
        throw res.error;
      else if (res.payload.status === 4)
        return { type: REQUEST_SCENE_PROCESSING_TASK_UPDATE_SUCCESS, task: res.payload }
      else
        return requestSceneProcessingTaskMessage(res.payload)
    })
    .retryWhen(errors => errors.delay(3000));
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is close.. it's looping but with the same response each time, it doesn't call the function requestSceneUpdates for each loop

Comment: like you've done but actually call the function each time.  Here it's only getting called the first time.

Answer (score 0):

This worked in the end, @Andrew fixed the first part.

```
    export function handleProcessingScenes(action$,store) {
  return action$.ofType(REQUEST_ALL_SCENES_BY_LOCATION_FULFILLED)
    .switchMap(({ scenesByLocation }) => Observable.from(scenesByLocation))
    .filter(scene => scene.scenePanoTask)
    .flatMap(scene => {
      return Observable.timer(0, 5000).takeUntil(action$.ofType( REQUEST_SCENE_PROCESSING_TASK_UPDATE_SUCCESS))
        .exhaustMap(() =>
          requestSceneUpdates(scene.id)
            .map((res) => {

              if (res.error) 
                return { type: REQUEST_SCENE_PROCESSING_TASK_UPDATE_FAILED, message: res.message }
              else if(res.payload.status === 4) 
                return { type: REQUEST_SCENE_PROCESSING_TASK_UPDATE_SUCCESS, task:  res.payload }
              else 
                return requestSceneProcessingTaskMessage(res.payload)
            })
            .catch(err => { return { type: REQUEST_SCENE_PROCESSING_TASK_UPDATE_FAILED, message: err } })
        )
    })
}
```